# How do you deal with people who downvote all your posts?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Almost all my posts have at least 1 downvote, so I was thinking a person must have gone through my history and downvoted everything I contributed. Is there a way to report this or do I just need to deal with it? Not that I care about reputation that much, but sometimes I need those rep to do stuff on SO. Any advice?

[image]

UPDATE :

[image]

Comment: That’s [meta-tag:serial-voting], and is usually automatically detected and reversed after a few days. If it continues and is not detected and reverted, you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention explaining what you believe is happening.

Comment: This looks particularly insidious.  The downvotes are in pairs of votes cast at the same time, but with the pairs spread out over days so as to avoid the script.  If all these votes are from the same user, (and it would be amazing if they were not), they need a slap.

Comment: I'd suggest flagging one of your downvoted posts, explaining in there that there's some serial downvoting going on (Link to this meta post too).

Comment: At what permission level do we get access to who cast down votes?  It would be interesting if we could come up with a script that shows % of downvotes that where cast by the same person on an account.  That might ketch this.

Comment: @DaImTo When you work at Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChrisHayes oh how sad, well I guess a girl can dream :)

Comment: @Gimby: Thse downvotes aren't caught by the system, so the answer there doesn't really answer this case.

Comment: @DaImTo: Moderators already have access to aggregate voting stats; we 'ketch' this all the time, but the automated script takes care of it the vast majority of the time.

Comment: The thing is you cant see who down voted you which I do understand it would probably be a bad idea to display who down votes you.  But In a case like this it would be nice to say that % of your down votes are by 1 person.  or maybe you have 101 down votes by 99 different people vs 101 down votes by 5 different people.  if you get my meaning.  The new profile page is amazing this could be added to it give us feed back on how we are doing.

Comment: @Cerbrus the answer is about what you (as the victim) can do, and at the same time explains the process. So I, and apparently others, do not agree with your assessment that it is not related.

Comment: @Gimby: The answer basically says: _"Do nothing"_... Since I was under the impression this was a pretty successful attempt at circumventing the system, that answer was inadequate. However, MartijnPieters' comment implies cases like these are detected also.

Comment: thanks, just report this to moderator, hopefully it will stop because I just got 3 more downvotes (at the same time) so the guy is probably write some script to crawl my profile page and downvote everything, but he's careful enough not to get caught by SO script. See updated picture.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, (and it probably won't:), it's happened to me too, but not as bad:   '  -2  14:30  downvote  SQLite callback causes recursive exceptions after a successful return
-2  14:29  downvote  Can a dynamically allocated shared_ptr delete itself via the dtor of the object it's managing?'