# Was my question off-topic?

Tags: support, specific-question

I was surprised to see an offtopic vote on [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313323/glsl-variable-turns-object-black/31334650).

[image]

After checking the help centre, I appear to meet almost all the criteria.

[image]

I definitely included the desired behaviour (with a screenshot), I included the actual behaviour (with another screenshot), and I definitely gave the shortest code that I could. The only thing I was missing was an error, which I couldn't provide because OpenGL didn't print out one.

I'd like to know why someone's voted to close it as offtopic, and what I could do to improve such questions in the future.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about a single close vote.

Comment: @Cerbrus Okay, but surely that means someone has voted to close a certain question. If their opinion is that it should be closed, wouldn't they have a good reason?

Comment: The fact that one close vote was cast and a bunch of people didn't pile on to actually close the question is a good indicator that you're not off-topic. Typically people waste no time in following someone's lead if a question really doesn't seem right.

Comment: Not every reason someone votes to close a question _is_ good.

Comment: @Joehot200 no, you can't trust in the fact that people vote with their brain - or vote when paying attention. do a search on meta for "robo reviewer", as an example.

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298944/how-do-you-deal-with-people-who-downvote-all-your-posts . Makes your one downvote seem rather inconsequential, don't you think ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it's not, your question appears perfectly on topic.

Not every reason someone votes to close a question is good. Some users don't pay nearly enough attention when close-voting, and some seem to be eager to close-vote questions simply because the sun came up in the east.

As [@Chris Hayes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1813853/chris-hayes) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298955/was-my-question-off-topic#comment218882_298955), the fact that people haven't jumped on the bandwagon to close your question, and that the one vote is the only one it's gotten, is a good indication your question isn't off-topic.